# DataTable in Shiny with shinytheme cyborg

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt, shinythemes

trying to get a dark theme to work with datatables (DT) package in a shiny application. I've tried `shinytheme("cyborg")` and also downloading the cyborg CSS sheet from Bootswatch, (for call in datatables, `style="bootstrap"`) but it doesn't seem to work when I use shinytheme. I need shinytheme for the rest of the app, since the css thows off all of the plots and spacing etc. **Is there a dark CSS I could use in place of shinythemes which would work with plotly and datatables?**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)

ui<-  fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cyborg"), 
            fluidRow(column(7, DTOutput("showdata")))
  )


server<-function(input, output) {
 output$showdata<- DT::renderDT({
   datatable(iris, rownames=F, filter="top", extensions = "Scroller", width = "100%", style="bootstrap",
             options = list(deferRender = TRUE, scrollY = 300,scrollX=FALSE, scroller = TRUE, dom = 'tp'),
             selection ='single' ) %>% 
     formatStyle(columns=colnames(iris),
      backgroundColor = '#282828', color = "white")
 })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[dark table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFohJ.png)
note that the main issue is the filter text does not appear (maybe it is white because of shinytheme)

Comment: sandstone is nice..the table is black but the header white.

Comment: thanks @MLavoie but I need a dark background for the whole app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the text visible if you set the font color to black. Just include some `CSS` in the header like: `div.dataTables_scrollHead span {color: black;}`

### Example UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
                tags$head(tags$style("div.dataTables_scrollHead span {color: black;}")),
                fluidRow(column(7, DTOutput("showdata")))
)
```

### Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much, @GyD! great CSS mastery. I've been trying at this forever!